# Is there a way to get to the HTML controls on an ASP.NET page?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am wondering if ASP.NET stores a reference to the HTML controls on an ASP.NET page. Does it store something like a server-side Document Object Model (DOM) for the HTML controls?

I believe qualifying my question with ASP.NET Web Forms or ASP.NET MVC would be irrelevant. However, still, if you were to ask, I am more interested in knowing about Web Forms. Does ASP.NET Web Forms store an object model for the HTML controls on the page?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Not trying to achieve anything. Just an academic question to satisfy my curiosity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add "runat="server" to most normal html controls, you can reference them in code-behind.

These are in the System.Web.UI.HtmlControls library.

Example:  an HtmlAnchor for the `<a>` tag can be found in MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlanchor.aspx) with a code sample at the end.

Comment: Cool. Thanks much. And I recall there's a different set of classes for the HTML controls. Where are these classes in the framework?

Comment: Not all html tags are supported. http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_refhtmlcontrols.asp

Comment: Thank you much. Now, another related question. Why would I want to do that? That is, why would I want to run Html controls at server?

Comment: @ArturUdod - Good point.  I added "most" to my answer to real "most normal html controls".  Thank you for reminding me!

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 - That would be a separate question - one I wouldn't answer because I don't know.  I've never used them myself.  Asking multiple quesitons in comments is not encouraged, but if that hasn't been asked already, that would make a decent question on its own.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 - one reason you might want to use the HTML controls versus the server controls is to force the rendered HTML to be of a certain element. For example, a `GridView` by default will render as an HTML table, but you may want it to render as DIVs for a table-less layout. It gives your more flexibility in the HTML output; one of the reasons people like ASP.NET MVC, because you are controlling more of the end result instead of the ASP.NET engine deciding certain things for you. Obviously, with power comes responsibility, you will lose some of the conveniences of server controls.

Comment: Thank you, Karl. If I wanted all the functionality of a GridView but I wanted it to render as DIV's, then how would having Html controls help? Also, I just asked this as a separate question now. If you please answer it there, I'd like to accept your answer as the correct one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18081332/why-would-i-run-html-controls-at-server